# Use of (ilaplace) give different result through sym variable and directly

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a symbolic variable, which contain, for example:

```
    p =

(9311.0*s + 6.12e9)/(s^2 + 8500.0*s + 3.61e11)
```

where s - also symbolic.
Then, if I use inverse laplace through variable p, then result is

```
>>result=vpa(ilaplace(p,s,n),3)
 result =
 exp(n*(- 4255.0 + 6.01e5*i))*(4666.0 - 5066.0*i) + exp(n*(- 4255.0 - 6.01e5*i))*(4666.0 + 5066.0*i)
```

But if I put expression directly, I will get what I expect (by formula in Korn's book or by definition):

```
vpa(ilaplace((9311.0*s + 6.12e9)/(s^2 + 8500.0*s + 3.61e11),s,n),3)

ans =

9311.0*exp(-4255.0*n)*(cos(6.01e5*n) + 1.09*sin(6.01e5*n))
```

Why? And what should I do to get right answer through variable?

P.S. vpa - is not influenced on main goal. It only left 3 digits in this case after point.

P.S.S. Added more code:

```
t = tf(linsys1) %linsys1 - from simulink circuit
%get coefficients from transfer function t
   [num,den] = tfdata(t);

   syms s n real 
   % convert transfer function to symbolic
   t_sym = poly2sym(cell2mat(num),s)/poly2sym(cell2mat(den),s);

   functionInMuPad=['partfrac(',char(t_sym),',s,Domain = R_)']; %collect expression in string format 
   simpleFraction=evalin(symengine,functionInMuPad); % sum of simple fractions (only MuPad allows get denominator of 2nd order)

  functionInMuPad2=['op(',char(simpleFraction),')']; %collect expression in string format 
   vectorOfOperand=evalin(symengine,functionInMuPad2); % vector of simple fractions

for k=1:length(vectorOfOperand)-1
z(k,1)=ilaplace(vectorOfOperand(k),s,n); 
end
```

So, something wrong with vectorOfOperand. 
ilaplace(vectorOfOperand(1)) gives complex result, but if copy (ctrl+c) value of vectorOfOperand(1) and make newVariable=Ctrl+V, then ilaplace(newVariable) - it's ok either in command window or in m-file:

```
bbb =(9313.8202564498255348020392071286*s + 6122529964.4040716985063406588769)/(8500.4056471180697831891961467533*s + s^2 + 360665607284.96754103451618653904);
ilaplace(bbb,s,n)
ans=9311.0*exp(-4255.0*n)*(cos(6.01e5*n) + 1.09*sin(6.01e5*n)) %after vpa
```

Kind of magic anyway. vectorOfOperand - is sym. I even made this:
vectorOfOperand=char(vectorOfOperand);
vectorOfOperand=sym(vectorOfOperand); it doesn't help..

Comment: Have you confirmed this? Further, have you looked at some plots to compare the results?

Comment: It looks like you may be just typing things directly into the Command Window rather than creating an M-file script/function and ensuring that you have no workspace conflicts. It's impossible for use to help you because you don't show all of the necessary code that you need to run this (and run it correctly). The first thing to try is `clear all` and the respecify everything needed in a script.

Comment: @horchler, I added all the code in main message, except simulink model though cause it's impossible. Also i tried clear all and make necessary symbol again.